# Nested query in JPQL

Tags: sql, database, jpa, jpql

I have 2 entities -

```
@Table(name = "MM_MONITORING_CARD")
@Entity(name = "mm_MonitoringCard")
public class MonitoringCard extends StandardEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CLIENT_ID")
private Counterparty client;

@Column(name = "START_DATE")
private LocalDate startDate;

@Column(name = "END_DATE")
private LocalDate endDate;

...otherColumn
}
```

and

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "MM_COUNTERPARTY")
@Entity(name = "mm_Counterparty")
@DiscriminatorValue("COUNTERPARTY")
@NamePattern("%s|name")
public class Counterparty extends StandardEntity {

@Column(name = "TYPE", insertable=false, updateable=false)
private String type;

...otherColumn
```

I need get all examples monitoringCard with condition - 1) between start date and end date 2) with Counterparty type = 'someType'

I do method -

```
List<MonitoringCard> monitoringCardList = dataManager.load(MonitoringCard.class)
.query("select distinct cm from mm_MonitoringCard m join mm_Counterparty cm where (m.current_date between cm.startDate and cm.endDate) and cm.type = :type")
.parameter("type", "someType")
.list();
```

but i get error, how can i make a correct request?
thanks

Comment: Is there no dependency mapped between mm_MonitoringCard and mm_Counterparty ?

Comment: mm_MonitoringCard have a field @ManyToOne Counterparty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correct. It should use a join like this:

```
select distinct m.Counterparty from mm_MonitoringCard m 
where (m.current_date between m.Counterparty.startDate and m.Counterparty.endDate) 
  and m.Counterparty.type = :type
```

In JPA you don't need to do an explicit join when navigating on a ToOne relationship.